# Facebook: retrieving Request object (from request_id) before authorization using JS SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

When a user comes into my app via an apprequest, Facebook appends a request_id to the URL.

I am trying to access this object before the user authorizes my application. When I try to make the api call:

```
FB.api('/'+requestId, function(response){ console.log(response); });
```

it returns the following:

```
error: Object
message: "An access token is required to request this resource."
```

But I should have access since it was my app that sent the request in the first place!

I did some digging, and I noticed that on the PHP side, it will use the user_access_token if available, and the app_access_token otherwise.

Is this a security limitation (i.e: cannot expose the app_access_token on the client side) or am I doing something wrong?

Any insight would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

when you make a request to /{user_id}/apprequests you have to have authorized the user already... 
Since the request was created by your application - only **your** application can manage -ie delete or read requests that were sent.  Essentially, before the user authorizes you app he/she is anonymous to your application - therefore it would not be possible to read that users requests because you "dont know" who they are...

Hope this helps...

Comment: But the request belongs to my application. My application should be able to access its own requests regardless of who the user is or even if there is a user logged in at all. Right?

Comment: not at all - if you send me a request - and i haven't added your app yet - why should your app be able to see my outstanding requests? The details in the request contain who sent the request and to whom it was sent (including facebook user ids)... an application doesn't have access to your user id until you have authorized it.

Comment: The application has access to all of that information as soon as the invite is sent, anyway. Furthermore, that doesn't explain why it is possible to access the request object before authorization from the serverside.

Comment: You can access the request that's being acted upon with your app token.  To get the balance of the users request you need to use the user token.

Answer (score -1):

The following blog posts describes how to interact with requests and should hopefully answer your questions.

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464

```
<?php 

  $app_id = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
  $app_secret = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';

  $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
    "client_id=" . $app_id .
    "&client_secret=" . $app_secret .
    "&grant_type=client_credentials";

  $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

  $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"]; 
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
  $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
  $user_id = $data["user_id"];

  //Get all app requests for user
  $request_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/" .
    $user_id . "/apprequests?" .
    $access_token;
  $requests = file_get_contents($request_url);

  //Print all outstanding app requests
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($requests);
  echo '</pre>';

  //Process and delete app requests
  $data = json_decode($requests);
  foreach($data->data as $item) {
    $id = $item->id;
    $delete_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" .
      $id . "?" . $access_token . "&method=delete";

    $result = file_get_contents($delete_url);
    echo("Requests deleted? " . $result);
  }
?>
```

You have access to the app generated requests as the user follows the request via your app token but you need the user token to access the rest of the users requests.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  Some people must not like to read or not understand the information in front of them.  Here's the code from the link that deciphers the request code